# Oauth2 google api flow step2 exchange requires root in Linux

Tags: python, oauth-2.0

I have a small job that uses the google drive API - at initial setup I capture credentials, but this only seems to work if the user is running as root in linux.

```
flow = flow_from_clientsecrets('client_secrets.json', OAUTH_SCOPE, REDIRECT_URI)
authorize_url = flow.step1_get_authorize_url()
print 'Go to the following link in your browser: \n' + authorize_url
code = raw_input('Enter verification code: ').strip()
credentials = flow.step2_exchange(code)
```

When I run that as a standard user I get:

```
ssl.SSLError: [Errno 185090050] _ssl.c:340: error:0B084002:x509 certificate routines:X509_load_cert_crl_file:system lib
```

Works fine when run by root, anyway to fix that?

UPDATE:
open("/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/httplib2-0.8-py2.7.egg/httplib2/cacerts.txt", O_RDONLY) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)

httplib2 installed as root? Could that be the issue?

Strace revealed that -- I added

```
httpfix = httplib2.http(disable_ssl_certificate_validation=True)
```

and changed

```
credentials = flow.step2_exchange(code,httpfix)
```

and it all worked

Comment: open("/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/httplib2-0.8-py2.7.egg/httplib2/cacerts.txt", O_RDONLY) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)

httplib2 installed as root? Could that be the issue?

Strace revealed that -- I added

httpfix = httplib2.http(disable_ssl_certificate_validation=True)
and changed

credentials = flow.step2_exchange(code,httpfix)

Comment: I get an error "module object is not callable" when i add httpfix = httplib2.http(disable_ssl_certificate_validation=True)